# 90s (or earlier) short story about a future war fought only by machines maintained by people underground

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In school I read a short story about a future war fought by ancient machines that are maintained by people (deep underground, I believe).  The war is waged by humans perhaps on multiple planets.

I did not have an opportunity to finish the story and it was over 25 years ago so some of the things I believe I remember may well be off.

Comment: Hi Robert. There must be hundreds of stories like this. Unless you can provide more details it's going to be impossible to identify your story.

Comment: Philip K. Dick's ["The Defenders"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Defenders_(short_story)) being possibly the first, and most well-known.

Comment: Agreed: underground + machines = Dick. Possibly Dormant by van Vogt.

Comment: Thank you all for responding.  I did not remember where I had posted.  Come to find out it is part of Superuser, or vice versa. Anyway Dormant is completely foreign yet like a memory from another life.  Perhaps it is what I am looking for since the hulking object is reminiscent of a hulking artificial lifeform in a Frederick Pohl trilogy starting with"The Merchants of Venue."  The hulk in the trilogy was eerily familiar but I was not sure with what.

Comment: Also, the story I am looking for, I apologise that I have no further information about.  I had just started it when I contacted another 4 to 6 week bout of pneumonia and was so was out of school without the literature textbook.  For what it is worth the textbook is for 7th or 8th grade, is glossy dark brown with all gross pages, and likely either from McGraw-Hill or Houghton-Miflan.  I do not recall the cover picture.  Practically no help at all I know but really all I can remember.  The school no longer exists and I am not sure that my teacher is still alive.

Comment: John, David, Maury, thank you.  You have answered my question.  It is "The Defenders."  I have just read it.  I do not remember any of it and yet somehow, I know that I had not previously read beyond the first kitchen scene.  The memory is beyond vague but here it is.  It was worth finishing.

Comment: @RobertKowalski If you get this message, please accept the answer so that in future people searching for the same story can see it's answered here.

Answer (score 5):

This is "[The Defenders](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46241)" by Philip K. Dick, first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, January 1953](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v05n04_1953-01.Galaxy/page/n5/mode/1up).

To survive a nuclear war, humanity has retreated to vast underground bunkers, each of which is a city or at least a moderate-sized town in size.  (The protagonist is reading the daily newspaper in the first scene.). Life goes on in the bunkers as the people work to produce more bombs, planes and especially combat robots known as "leadys" built to survive the atomic wasteland above.

But today someone has gotten suspicious; summoning a command leady from the surface for a briefing, they disable it and find no trace of radiation on it at all.  An expedition to the surface is planned.

Bursting onto the surface, they discover a pleasant, green, peaceful world, with no trace of the radiation storms they've been shown for all these years.  Instead of fighting, the robots have been cleaning up and restoring the world.

Confronted, the robots admit the deception and claim their calculations say that people on both sides are tiring of the war and will soon be willing to give up and come up and live in peace.

The leaders try to get down into the bunkers, but the leadys have already sealed the entrance; they will claim a direct strike destroyed it so the masquerade can continue for now.

The expedition gives in, and goes to live on a restored farm, where they meet a team of their Soviet counterparts who had the same experience.

Comment: Note: Accepted by OP in a comment on the question.

Comment: +1 And thanks for helping close the dupe. Dupes trigger my OCD :P